# How do I enable my radio button to work with the conditions that I desired?

Tags: html, reactjs, database

**Here is my code:**

```
<div className="form-group row mb-3">
  <div className="col-sm-2" style={{ fontSize: "1rem" }}>
    Test:{" "}
  </div>
  <div className="col-sm-4">
    <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input
        className="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="testy"
        id="testy"
        value="y"
        disabled={test?.a === "V" || test?.b != null}
        checked={test?.c === true}
        onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.checked)}
      />
      <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="testy">
        Yes
      </label>
    </div>
    <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input
        className="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="testn"
        id="testn"
        value="n"
        disabled={test?.a === "V" || test?.b != null}
        checked={test?.c === false}
        onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.checked)}
      />
      <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="testn">
        No
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

I have incoming data from a database that returns me a boolean and to reflect that in my radio button, I assigned it to `checked`. So if `test?.c` from the database is true, it will pick the yes radio button to be selected and if the value is false, it will pick the no radio button to be selected. This part is what I wanted and it is working.

But if i dont have a boolean returned from database, i would like to allow user to select which radio button to be clicked. But at the moment I cannot click any radio button currently. I found out the issue is because I am using `checked`. But without using this `checked`, i cant display the existing selection that is stored in database. Is anyone here familiar with radio buttons that can guide me on what I can do to fix this.

Basically what I want to do is to be able to display the result that is returned from the database `test?.c`, if there is no data from `test?.c`, I want to allow user to select the radio button to send the selected radio button to database to store in  `test?.c` so if user display this page, it will extract the `test?.c` from db and display it

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the functionality you're looking for, you can modify your code to handle both scenarios. If test?.c is present, set the checked property based on its value. If it is not present, allow the user to interact with the radio buttons and store the selected value in the test?.c property. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Assuming you have a functional component
const YourComponent = () => {
  // State to manage the radio button selection
  const [test, setTest] = useState({});

  // Simulating the effect of fetching data from the database
  useEffect(() => {
    // Replace this with your actual data fetching logic
    // For demonstration purposes, using a setTimeout to simulate an asynchronous operation
    const fetchDataFromDatabase = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Assuming this is the data you get from the database
        const dataFromDatabase = {
          c: true // or false, or undefined if there is no data
        };
        setTest(dataFromDatabase);
      }, 1000); // Simulating a delay
    };

    fetchDataFromDatabase();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures the effect runs only once

  // Event handler for radio button change
  const handleRadioChange = (value) => {
    setTest({
      ...test,
      c: value
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-group row mb-3">
      <div className="col-sm-2" style={{ fontSize: '1rem' }}>
        Test:{' '}
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-4">
        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input
            className="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="testy"
            id="testy"
            value="y"
            disabled={test?.a === 'V' || test?.b != null}
            checked={test?.c === true}
            onChange={() => handleRadioChange(true)}
          />
          <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="testy">
            Yes
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input
            className="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="testn"
            id="testn"
            value="n"
            disabled={test?.a === 'V' || test?.b != null}
            checked={test?.c === false}
            onChange={() => handleRadioChange(false)}
          />
          <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="testn">
            No
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use any conditioanl expression there like `test?.c==true` or `false` especially *optional chaining(?.)*

Just leave it as it is and use `defaultChecked` attribute instead `checked`.

`defaultChecked` is the uncontrolled equivalent, which sets whether the component is checked when it is first mounted

```
<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={test.c} />
```

One more thing you don't have to use `?.` unless you want to get the inner property

for example:

```
let test = {
    c:true,
    inner:{
      c:false
    }
}
```

For a case, we can avoid `undefined` error while getting `test.inner2?.c` here inner2 is also an object but we don't know about it's existance.